# SSDP replies from 192.168.1.1. What exactly is at this ip address?

Tags: windows-10, wireshark, network-protocols, upnp

When I send a crafted ssdp request packet with ssdp:all to 239.255.255.250, an address 192.168.1.1 replies with a bunch of HTTP 1.1 OK ssdp messages(captured on Wireshark). Are these ssdp services that this device at that address is offering? What is at this address because I've seen it around in other home networks as well.

Comment: `192.168.1.1` is typically your gateway (the modem in most cases). If you are on a windows machine and wish to confirm this theory, type `/ipconfig` from a command line and you should see the gateway for your device, which is more than likely this IP address.

Comment: And as many home-routers have UPNP enabled by default it is perfectly normal for a home-router to respond to ssdp requests.

Comment: @EricF Why the `/` in `/ipconfig`? It won't work.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Because I typed quickly, have been living inside of Debian, and accidently added it :) Do so without the slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSDP is used to detect automatically network services.
When you send a crafted SSDP request on a multicast address (such as 239.255.255.250), all devices providing this kind of services should respond with an SSDP "Notify" packet.

The data of these answer packets are structured like an HTTP header and contains information about the services provided by the host.

In your case, you receive answer from 192.168.1.1. This address is often used by the default Gateway of the network.

The default gateway of the network often provide UPnP services, especially for port mapping.

Comment: The MSEARCH query that I am sending includes the ST field which is set to ssdp:all does this mean that it's asking for all the upnp services that all the upnp devices on the network are offering? I get an HTTP 1.1 200 OK type of message when I look at it from Wireshark.

Comment: ST field is used to set the type of device you'r looking for. By using "ssdp:all", all ssdp devices receiving your query will answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question, is there a field I can use to specify the type of service I'm looking for?

Comment: It can be specified in ST field too. You could find more information in the "Device Architecture" document on upnp.org.

Comment: Alright I'll check out upnp.org thank you!